# Intercept a token passed through an URL to a Flutter web app hosted on Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, jwt, firebase-hosting

I've developed an website in Flutter that I've deployed on Firebase. What I want to achieve is to redirect the user of an app to this website using an URL that also contains an JWT token because there will be some authenticated requests to be done on the website - but the website doesn't have any login page.

Is it possible to retrieve that token in order to be used in the code of the website?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firebase Hosting, all traffic between the client and server goes over an SSL-encrypted connection, so the data can only be seen by the sender and received (unless your certificate chain is compromised).

If you pass the token in the URL, anyone can see it, as the URL is not encrypted. So you'll want to send the token in (for example) a header, such as the pre-defined `Authorization` header of HTTP. This is actually what the Firebase JavaScript SDKs themselves do to pass authentication information to the Firebase server.s

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I'm afraid I've misused the term intercept. Right now I'm not concerned about security. What I want to do is to use that token passed through the URL in the code of the site.

Comment: Sounds possible. What's the problem you have when implementing that?

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea how that can be implementing, so I don't even know where to begin Googling. The curent idea that I have is that I will need to run some sort of a script on the root page of the domain that will extract that token that I pass with the URL.

Comment: I think you may be looking for this: https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+web+determine+url+parameters

Comment: Thanks a lot. Eventually my coding partner found a solution: a JS script that captures the URL and that can be called in the Flutter code. Thank you for your time.